# Poll a Web Worker's message queue

Tags: web-worker

Is it possible to poll the number of unprocessed onmessage's or the actual messages themselves in a Web Worker instance?

For instance: `myWorker.unprocessedMessages` etc. Alternatively check if a Web Worker is busy. I want to be able to distribute messages to free Web Workers.

Also proposed custom solutions are welcome. I don't just want to do a round robin.

Answer (score 0):

Web workers message queue is not special from rest of JavaScript event queue. And you cannot access any information about that.

I wish I could help more, but you will need to solve this with completely different approach.